# Link to send private message to current user in the node (author of the content)?

Tags: privatemsg

Is it possible to create a link to send private message to CURRENT USER in the node (to the author of the node content to be more precise). I'm using the Privatemsg module.
I was trying to do this with the Display suite dynamic fields, but I am not able.

I found that the Privatemsg module comes with an option to "Display link on the selected content types. So, I have the "contact current member link" right in the content type, but it shows only for logged in users.

Is there any configuration or hook that I can implement to show the same link to anonymous user?

This is the code that shows the link.

```
function privatemsg_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
  $types = array_filter(variable_get('privatemsg_link_node_types', array()));
  $url = privatemsg_get_link(user_load($node->uid));
  if (in_array($node->type, $types) && !empty($url) && ($view_mode == 'full' || (variable_get('privatemsg_display_on_teaser', 1) && $view_mode == 'teaser'))) {
    $node->content['links']['#links']['privatemsg_link'] = array(
      'title' => t('Contact member'),
      'href' => $url . '/' . t('Message regarding @node', array('@node' => $node->title)),
      'query' => drupal_get_destination(),
      'attributes' => array('class' => 'button radius privatemsg-send-link privatemsg-send-link-node'),
    );
  }
}
```

To make it clearer, I don't want anonymous user to send messages. What I want is just a link to log in for anonymous users. Expressing it with pseudo-code...

```
global $user;

if (isset($user->roles[1])) {
  // Do not show button to Anonymous user and show something else or a button to log in (THE CODE FOR LOG IN)
  echo "something else";
}
else {
  // Show button to logged in user (the code of "Send author a message" button)
}
```

Comment: look at [this](https://drupal.org/node/1356340) and [this](https://drupal.org/node/1360752) post...you can find the answer, or at least can be helpful...

Comment: mixerowsky, thank you alot for your answer. The links you have shared is very helpful, anyway, i found that privatemsg module comes with an option to "Display link on the selected content types", and with that, you have a link "Send author a message" right in the content type or node that you want. This link can be customized with css and the text can be altered with stringoverrides‎ module. Thank you bro ;)

Comment: Hello again mixerowsky. Do you know how to show that link to anonymous user also? Thank you

Comment: @user1754562 Privatemsg links don't work for anonymous.  There is an outstanding feature request for this: https://drupal.org/node/1988848

Comment: yes, it is impossible to send private message to anonymous user, that user is not registered...

Comment: But I DON'T want to send private message to anonymouse users (I know that this is impossible). I just want to show that link ("Send Author a Message") to anonymouse user also. Right now it show only for logged in users. thank you

Comment: There is no need to show that link, you can add link to send email to node author...try with [Contact Link](https://drupal.org/project/contactlink) or [Node feedback](https://drupal.org/project/node_feedback) module...

Comment: That's a request of my client. I'm working on it, to show that link to the anonymous users... Or maybe a link to redirect to login page. I'll be back when i did it. Thank you

Comment: than you can create field with custom text and link to login page and show that field only for anonymous users using [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module...

Comment: Privatemsg does not support private messages from anonymous users, that's why there's no link. You can't add it.

Comment: Pleaseee, understand me! I don't want anonymous user to send message.What I want is just a link to login, when the user is logged out. Just that

Comment: I've found the solution. It is explained in the answer below. Thank you

Comment: I've found the solution. It is explained in the answer below. There was no need to use that module. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with a Display suite custom code field. With it I am able to use some PHP code.

```
global $user;
// If the user is anonymous (role=1) show this; otherwise show nothing.
if (isset($user->roles[1])) {
  print l(t('Contact member'), 'user/login', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('radius', 'button'))));
}
```

So, when the user is logged-in, this code above will be replaced with the contact member link (*Send author a message*).